# error in response from dialog.elicitslot()

Tags: c#, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am trying to make a simple quiz game for Alexa where the user is presented with two events and tries to guess wheter the first second event came before or after the second event.

the game requires a slot called "answer" to be filled. 
My problem is that my DialogElicitSlot() method is causing an error and Alexa is not able to read out the response.

Any help is appreciated, and if someone has a working example (using C#) of something similar that would also be great :)

```
[assembly: 
LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace Timeline
{
 public class Function
 {

    /// <summary>       
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="input"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private SkillResponse MakeResponse(string outputSpeech, bool shouldEndSession, string repromptSpeech)
    {
        var response = new ResponseBody
        {
            ShouldEndSession = shouldEndSession,
            OutputSpeech = new PlainTextOutputSpeech { Text = outputSpeech }
        };

        var skillResponse = new SkillResponse
        {
            Response = response,
            Version = "1.0"
        };

        return skillResponse;
    }

    public IOutputSpeech GetOutputSpeech(string response)
    {
        return new PlainTextOutputSpeech()
        {
            Text = response
        };
    }



    public SkillResponse FunctionHandler(SkillRequest input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        var requestType = input.GetRequestType();
        if (requestType == typeof(IntentRequest))
        {

            var intentRequest = input.Request as IntentRequest;

            if (intentRequest != null)
            {

                switch (intentRequest.Intent.Name)
                {
                    case "nextEvent":
                        {
                            string lastEventName = QuestionController.getPreviousEventName();
                            DateTime lastEventDate = QuestionController.getPreviousEventDate();

                            string nextEventName = QuestionController.getNextEventName();
                            DateTime nextEventDate = QuestionController.getNextEventDate();

                            if (intentRequest.DialogState == DialogState.Started)
                            {
                                return ResponseBuilder.DialogElicitSlot(GetOutputSpeech($"did the {lastEventName} happen before, or after {nextEventName} ?"), intentRequest.Intent.Slots["answer"].Name, intentRequest.Intent);

                            }
                            else if (intentRequest.DialogState != DialogState.Completed)
                            {
                                return ResponseBuilder.DialogElicitSlot(GetOutputSpeech($"did the {lastEventName} happen before, or after {nextEventName} ?"), intentRequest.Intent.Slots["answer"].Name, intentRequest.Intent);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var questionEvaluation = intentRequest.Intent.Slots["answer"].Value;

                                if (QuestionController.evaluateAnswer() == true)
                                {
                                    return MakeResponse($"That is correct! The {nextEventName} was {questionEvaluation} the {lastEventName}. The {nextEventName} was in {nextEventDate} while the {lastEventName} was in {lastEventDate}", true, "");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return MakeResponse($"That is wrong! The {nextEventName} was not {questionEvaluation} the {lastEventName}. The {nextEventName} was in {nextEventDate} while the {lastEventName} was in {lastEventDate}", true, "");
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    default:
                        return MakeResponse("hmm. i dont think i understand what you are asking of me", false, "");
                }
            }
            return MakeResponse("",false,"");

        }
        else
        {
            return MakeResponse("Welcome", false, "");

        }
    }
}
}
```

`

The response that i am getting when i test my skill is

```
{
"body": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "response": {
        "outputSpeech": {
            "type": "PlainText",
            "text": "did the previous event happen before, or after next event ?"
        },
        "directives": [
            {
                "type": "Dialog.ElicitSlot",
                "updatedIntent": {
                    "name": "nextEvent",
                    "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
                    "slots": {
                        "answer": {
                            "name": "answer",
                            "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "slotToElicit": "answer"
            }
        ],
        "shouldEndSession": false
    }
}
```

}

Also - if anyone could tell me how i can make the slot a required value working from the code i would be gratefull.

Comment: You got this input when you tested it on skill tester beta? And alexa is unable to speak the text? Is it the actual problem here?

Comment: Exactly :-).. Sorry if that wasn’t clear.

Comment: When I feel there is something magically wrong going on with my skill, I see the `Device Log` in the **Test** section of Alexa builder. You need to see last 4 - 5 logs, somewhere there would be hidden the precise reason of error, written in quotes. You might find something in `Directive: SkillDebugger.CaptureDebugging`, look for it.